# JQuery Find Next Element Inside Table Row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this function:

```
$("span.expandimg").click(function(){
  $(this).nextAll(".toggle_container:first").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

That worked fine with:

```
<span class="expandimg"><a href="#"><img id="iexpand" src="images/expand.png" border="0" /><img id="icollapse" src="images/collapse.png" border="0" /></a></span>&nbsp;<a href="asdfa" class="DSF">First Link</a>

<div class="toggle_container">
Some Text
</div>
```

But now I'm putting "expandimg" inside a table column and "toggle_container" inside another column. Something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><span class="expandimg">......</td>
  <td><div class="toggle_container">.....</td>
<tr>
```

How can I find the "toggle_container" element now? I want to click on "expandimg" to expand the "toggle_container", but it's not working with the function I have.

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: Yes, I think you should use .parent(): $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggle_container')...
http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: @RaduBilei: Any reason why you're not posting that as answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("span.expandimg").click(function(){
    $(this)
        .closest("tr")
        .find("td .toggle_container")
        .slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML you currently have this should work -

```
$("span.expandimg").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings().find(".toggle_container:first").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/QAkKP/

Comment: No need to do `siblings` and then `find`, go straight to `find`.

Comment: Actually you had it right, you were doing it another way, which is probably slower depending on the amount of table cells the OP will have there. Also, it is unnecessary to construct an object with all the `td` elements of that `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span.expandimg").click(function(){
  $(this).parents("tr").find(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Goes up to the parent TR element, searches that for the .toggle_container.

Should work :)

Comment: This will be way slower than `closest`, moreover it will construct an object of the entire parents tree not only the direct one.